# pyscripter auto-suggestions with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for Programmers, but I thought it was a better fit here than on SO.  I have these significant lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
```

Specifically in PyScripter, I cannot see most functions of pygame.  For example, I cannot see anything in locals.  If I type *pygame.* , then a list pops up with

```
Color
MissingModule
os
packager_imports
string
sys
warnings
warn_unwanted_files
color_constructor
color_reduce
rect_constructor
rect_reduce
__version__
```

However, I believe that there are missing elements, at least according to [the pygame reference](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/index.html).  Such elements would include (I think) all of the modules loaded by pygame, so it is a big deal that I can get these auto-suggestions to work.  What might I need to change in order to be able to access this from Pyscripter?  (If this is difficult, would there be a simple workaround?)

Comment: Most Python auto-completion programs have trouble with completing things that have been imported with `from x import *`, since these just get imported into the global namespace. I'm not sure that there is any good workaround.

Comment: That's more or less what I figured, unfortunately.  However, beyond the imports into the global namespace, I cannot seem to import things from the pygame namespace using _pygame._, which is not part of the global namespace.  I can import the modules given above, but I seem to be missing a great majority of them.  By the way, the modules work - I've used the code - but it isn't recognized in PyScripter.

Comment: This probably won't concern your problem, but are you using the readline module for auto completion?

Comment: Probably not, unless tooltips count as part of it.  I'm not using any extra modules like that myself, though (I'm not familiar with the module you're talking about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Japanese and I'm just beginning to use python and pygame.
When I bought a new PC, I downloaded Pyscripter, python 3.3, and pygame.
As you said, Pyscripter couldn't work with the pygame namespace.
Pyscripter emitted only the above code in the list.
The only function of pygame that displayed was Color.
I didn't know what to do with pygame in Pyscripter.
But, I tried to write a python interpreter attached to Pyscripter.

And I wrote as follows:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.quit()
```

At that time, I still hoped that it would work.  Pyscripter could work with pygame.
I wrote the codes and I finished pygamewindow at the same time.
Then, I returned to the original browser (whatever it's called).
It was either repaired or recognized.
I was very bothered at first, but when I think about the later invention, that is not suffered.
However, there is a downside to this solution.  If I write a code, for example;

```
pygame.surface.Surface
```

Auto-completion, in the middle of the above code, didn't emerge.
I have no idea why it didn't, but now I write all of my code with Pyscripter.
It is a little inconvenient, but it made is easier to program.  If you solved this problem and understand the reason for it, please let me know.  I hope that this will help you and others. Bye.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this is answers the question, but I chose to accept it because you're really the only person who responded, which takes some effort.